# Javascript: Get ID of all Elements starting with same characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I just despair of the following Javascript function.

There are several elements on the page that start with the same ID. The number of IDs is different depending on the user input. Also the ID is not continuous. But the number is always four digits long:

```
<section id="mirror_element_0001"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0002"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0401"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_1039"></section>
...
```

I need a function that gives me all complete IDs of the elements. So for the example above, I need the following output:

```
mirror_element_0001
mirror_element_0002
mirror_element_0401
mirror_element_1039
...
```

With `myStringArray = $('[id^="mirror_element_"]');`i get the whole Element. And `myStringArray().substr(0, 4)` will fail with an error.

Can you guys help me out?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a collection of all the elements, map them to their IDs. No need for a big library like jQuery for something this trivial:

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mirror_element_"]')]
    .map(elm => elm.id)
);
```

```html
<section id="mirror_element_0001"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0002"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0401"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_1039"></section>
```

Comment: Wow great!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach.

`const result = [...myStringArray].map(section => $(section).attr('id'))`

```js
const myStringArray = $('[id^="mirror_element_"]');

const result = [...myStringArray].map(section => $(section).attr('id'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="mirror_element_0001"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0002"></section>
<section id="mirror_element_0401"></section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<section id="mirror_element_1039"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are always welcome. If my solution helps you then please mark this as resolved.